# Wordpress piotnetforms plugin how to run Jquery code after form submission

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form on my Wordpress page created by piotnetforms and I would like to run a Jquery code, after the form submit.

this is the link for the form:
[the form Link](https://swtsh.dev/bma-components-test-2/)

This is the code I have :

```
jQuery("#formID").submit(function() {
 
   alert("submited");

 });
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.

Comment: This problem needs more details in order to be solved! Please show us your form html structure with its classes and ids.

Comment: @Mokhless  I built the form using piotnet forms plugin

Comment: I've linked the form url

Answer (score 3):

From the link you gave us, it seems that your submit button has an event listener which has `e.preventDefault()`. It means `submit` event never fires! You can change the event you're listening for, to `click` event.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.piotnetforms-button').on('click', function () {
    alert("submit button clicked!");
  })
})
```

Comment: i need to confirm that the form submitted then run the code

Comment: in this case i can run the code without filing the form and that d'ont work for me

Comment: Of curse, you need to validate the fields and make sure they have values. I thought your question was about why `submit` event doesn't work. Even if `submit` event would have worked, you would have needed to validate your fields. If you're not sure how to validate your fields, let me know. I can give you an example on how to validate your fields on a `click` event.

Comment: yes I would like an exmple please
that will help me a lot